# Convert SQL with groupBy sub query to LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Please could somebody assist me in an example of the following SQL into a LINQ query in C#, I am using .NET 4.0.

```
       SELECT x.*
          FROM [eBookAddict].[dbo].[UrlRecord] x
          JOIN (SELECT t.Slug
                  FROM [eBookAddict].[dbo].[UrlRecord] t
              GROUP BY t.Slug
                HAVING COUNT(t.Slug) = 2) y ON y.Slug = x.Slug
```

Many Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Somewaht similar but for many to many relation. Url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427210/how-can-i-write-a-inner-join-query-using-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from x in db.UrlRecord

join y in db.UrlRecord.GroupBy(rec => rec.Slug).Where(grp => grp.Count == 2)
on y.Key equals x.Slug

select x;
```

Comment: thanks, just needed to change the 3rd line to on x.slug = y.key, very fast response, cheers mate.